# Remove parenthesis from itertools.combinations list

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools, parentheses

I want to make a list of all possible combinations in a range of numbers, and print them  line by line without surrounding parentheses. Here is the code I've built so far.

```
import itertools

x = range(1,4
y = list(itertools.combinations(x,2))

combos = []
for i in range(len(y)):
       combos.append(y[i])
       print(combos[i])
```

The output is

```
(1,2)
(1,3)
(2,3)
```

I need it to print the output without surrounding parentheses. I've looked high and low for a solution, but so far I can't find anything. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @cat_herder Why are you building the list `combos` when you already have the list `y`?

Comment: @BenGrossmann because I'm overcomplicating things.

Comment: @nonDucor that print statement gives me the following error. TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, tuple found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple way to do this.

```
import itertools

x = range(1,4)
y = list(itertools.combinations(x,2))

for pair in y:
    print(*pair)
```

If you really want the separating commas, you could do this:

```
import itertools

x = range(1,4)
y = list(itertools.combinations(x,2))

for pair in y:
    print(f"{pair[0]},{pair[1]}")
```